# Activity reopening is working only once

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

I have receiver and when some action is happening I need to reopen current activity(I am in HideSettingsActivity and I want to close that Activity and open the new one HideSettingsActivity). For this I'm just finishing current activity and open the new one via intent. Code below.

```
Intent reopenCurrentActivityIntent = new Intent(this, HideSettingsActivity.class);
                reopenCurrentActivityIntent.putExtra(CURRENT_PASSWORD, passwordDialog.getPassword());
                startActivity(reopenCurrentActivityIntent);
                finish();
```

The problem is, that it's working only for first time,when receiver is gettings some action. Next times, opening new activity is not working. Other lines of code, which are before and after that piece of code, which I described above, they works fine.
So the question is, why it is happening like that? And maybe there are some others way, to reopen current activity?

Comment: next time ? what do you mean by next time?

Comment: @SantatuSur I have a QR-Scanner. I want to reopen this activity each time, when I scan some QR-codes. So reopening activity is working only for first time, when I'm scanning QR-code.

Comment: you are opening the activity in which you are already in ? ryt?

Comment: @SantatuSur Yes. I need to reopen current activity.

Comment: i am updaing the answer..

Comment: take a look at this library for faster implementation: https://github.com/kostasdrakonakis/android_navigator

Answer (score 0):

Add flag `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT));` to your intent.. like :-

```
reopenCurrentActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT));
```

then,

`startActivity(reopenCurrentActivityIntent);`
and its better to use this :-

```
Intent reopenCurrentActivityIntent = new Intent(HideSettingsActivity.this, HideSettingsActivity.class);
```